# Possible to pass type object to constructor that accepts an unknown var type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been looking for a way to pass an object as unknown type in c# without casting the object?

Essentially I am using reflection to grab the constructor parameters of a class, and I have variables that are casted as objects that I need to pass to the constructor, except I have found no way to dynamically cast the vars...

Code Sample:

```
public class bClass {
    public bClass(string c) {
        d = c;
    }
}

object a = "asdfasdf";
bClass b = new bClass(a);
```

I have been able to get the type of variable bClass accepts in the constructor using

```
var obj = typeof(bClass).GetConstructors();
foreach(var nObj in obj) {
    foreach(var param in nObj) {
        string sAObjectType = param.ParameterType;
    }
}
```

however, I am not sure how to cast 'a' to type sAObjectType, any ideas are greatly appreciated =]

Thank you!

Comment: Look at [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `a` is already a string.  If it isn't a string, what would you want to do?

Comment: Have you tried using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wcxyzt4d) to invoke the constructor instead?

Comment: Convert.ChangeType returns an 'object', I am looking into CreateInstance now

Comment: Same with Activator.CreateInstance =[

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts: I'm not clear on what your question is, now. `Activator.CreateInstance` returns an `object`, but you can cast this to the type you want (in this case, `bClass`).

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts, you might need to combine generics with `Activator`. For example, a method could be defined `public T GetInstance<T>()`, and would `return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2, ...) as T`. To call it, do something like `var myBClass = GetInstance<bClass>()` On a side note, you might want to look at the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): "In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without specifying the exact class"

Comment: @Jeoroen I am looking to dynamically cast objects, example, I would like to do the following, object obj = "234", Type type = typeof(string); bClass b = new bClass((type)obj);

Answer (score 0):

What about using generics - then you don't have to worry to much about conversion etc.

```
public class bClass<T> 
{
    privat T d;

    public bClass(T c)
    {
        d = c
    }
}
```

Then things like below will work.

```
bClass b1 = new bClass( "1234" );
bClass b2 = new bClass( 12 );
...
```

Comment: Interesting, let me give that a try =]